# DevEcoStudio: No SDK file downloaded on installing DevEcoStudio

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

[image: I have provided a screenshot of the error]I have an issue in downloading SDK file in version 3.0.0.800. After I installed DevEcoStudio I realized that SDK file did not get installed with it. So when I go to "Configure-> Settings-> HarmonyOS Legacy SDK" it shoes error as "Network connection failed. Check the network or HTTP proxy settings."

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this, If yes, how ?!

Answer (score 14):

Check whether the network is limited. If the network is limited, configure a proxy.

The other possible cause is that the system language of the PC is English and the region code is `US`. You could try to perform the following operations to change the region code to `CN`. Before changing the region code, close DevEco Studio.

In the `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Huawei\DevEcoStudio3.0\options` directory, open the `country.region.xml` file and change `countryregion` name to `CN`.

```
<application>

<component name="CountryRegionSetting">

<countryregion name="CN"/>

</component>

</application>
```

Comment: For Mac OS:
~/Library/Application Support/Huawei/DevEcoStudio3.0/options/country.region.xml

Answer (score 0):

According to one of the Huawei dev, DevEco Studio 3.0 Beta 2+ that has the local emulator support doesn't work outside of China as of now. @shirley's answer to override the country allows to install the SDK, but yet to verify if this causing any quirks on the roadmap ahead -

[image]

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0202835968846400103